# Jest unit test fails but it shouldnt

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs

I have this method that returns Boolean. It works as it should but in unit tests it fails.
The method looks like this:

```
 const isRushHour = (date: string): boolean => {
  let isRushHour: boolean = false;
  let isFriday: boolean = new Date(date).getDay() === 5;
  let selectedTime: string = new Date(date).toLocaleTimeString(
    navigator.language,
    {
      hour: "2-digit",
      minute: "2-digit",
    }
  );

  let isRushHourRange: boolean =
    selectedTime >= "15:00" &&
    selectedTime <= "19:00" ;

  if (isFriday && isRushHourRange) {
    isRushHour = true;
  }

  return isRushHour;
};
```

it Basically checks if date is friday and if it its between the time range. However everything is fine when checking with console f.ex;

```
console.log(isRushHour("2022-01-07T19:00"))
```

This will return true and it should be like this !

But in jest i tried with `.toBe(true) , .toBeTruthy() , and to toEqual(true)`

```
    expect(calculator.isRushHour("2022-01-07T19:00")).toBe(true);
```

Exactly the same string.

But the test fails with message :

```
   expect(received).toBe(expected) // Object.is equality

    Expected: true
    Received: false
```

Comment: The return value of `isRushHour` will vary based on what `navigator.language` returns. What does it return for you?

Comment: ```navigator.language returns``` = ```en-Gb```
```isRushHourRange``` returns = ```true```

Comment: Does `navigator.language` return `en-GB` in your test?

Comment: Thanks you so much ! that was the issue. it was en-Us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed the issue:

```
   beforeEach(() => {
  jest.spyOn(window.navigator, "language", "get");
});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).